# Dataframe create column with number of total sales

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a game sales table. When a game is sold several times, its ID appears several times.

With value_counts, I know how many times each game is sold.

But, I would like to create a column in my table that specifies this.I would like to have the following columns:

game / purchase date / customer / price / game genre / total number of sales

Is this possible?

Update:

@constantstranger
@Timus

Thank you so much for the efficient and detailed answer !

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of input data or a small DataFrame with examples of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'game':['game1', 'game1', 'game2', 'game1', 'game3', 'game2'],
    'customer':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'e'],
    'price':[20, 20, 24, 20, 18, 24],
    'game genre':['FPS', 'FPS', 'Action RPG', 'FPS', 'Tactical RGP', 'Action RPG']})
df['total number of sales'] = df.apply(lambda x:sum(x['game'] == df['game']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    game customer  price    game genre  total number of sales
0  game1        a     20           FPS                      3
1  game1        b     20           FPS                      3
2  game2        c     24    Action RPG                      2
3  game1        d     20           FPS                      3
4  game3        c     18  Tactical RGP                      1
5  game2        e     24    Action RPG                      2
```

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out in a comment by @Timus, this can also be done as follows:

```py
df['total number of sales'] = df.groupby('game').game.transform('count')
```

Here is some code to show exactly what is going on in this statement:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'game':['game1', 'game1', 'game2', 'game1', 'game3', 'game2'],
    'customer':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'e'],
    'price':[20, 20, 24, 20, 18, 24],
    'game genre':['FPS', 'FPS', 'Action RPG', 'FPS', 'Tactical RGP', 'Action RPG']})

print("\n======= df.groupby('game')")
print(df.groupby('game'))
print("\n======= df.groupby('game').game")
print(df.groupby('game').game)
print("\n======= df.groupby('game').game.transform('count')")
print(df.groupby('game').game.transform('count'))
print(f"The above object has type:", type(df.groupby('game').game.transform('count')))
df['total number of sales'] = df.groupby('game').game.transform('count')
print("\n======= df after this statement: df['total number of sales'] = df.groupby('game').game.transform('count')")
print(df)
```

The output is:

```
======= df.groupby('game')
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000001F0AB9D2B00>

======= df.groupby('game').game
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x000001F0AB9D2B00>

======= df.groupby('game').game.transform('count')
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    3
4    1
5    2
Name: game, dtype: int64
The above object has type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

======= df after this statement: df['total number of sales'] = df.groupby('game').game.transform('count')
    game customer  price    game genre  total number of sales
0  game1        a     20           FPS                      3
1  game1        b     20           FPS                      3
2  game2        c     24    Action RPG                      2
3  game1        d     20           FPS                      3
4  game3        c     18  Tactical RGP                      1
5  game2        e     24    Action RPG                      2
```

The call to `groupby()` returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` object, and the `.game` (which is equivalent to `['game']`) returns a `SeriesGroupBy` object. The call to `transform('count')` passes to `transform()` the string name of a function `count` which gets called for each group in the `SeriesGroupBy` object so that `transform()` can do the following according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html):

> Call function producing a like-indexed Series on each group and return a Series having the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values.

In other words, `groupby()` creates an object (call it `g`) which collects groups of all the rows in df with the same 'game' value, and `g['game'].transform('count')` takes the 'game' column of this object and uses it to (1) count the number of rows for each 'game' value and (2) return a `Series` **with the same indexes as `df`** and with a value at each index that is the row count in df corresponding to the value of the 'game' column for that index.

While the approach using `transform()` may not be the easiest to understand for those just starting out with Pandas, as pointed out by @Timus, this idiom is more efficient than the first solution above.

Comment: Wouldn't `df['total number of sales'] = df.groupby('game').game.transform('count')` be more efficient?

Comment: @Timus Yes, your suggestion is indeed more efficient (though potentially with a bit of a learning curve for those new to Pandas). I have updated my answer to incorporate (and annotate) your suggested statement.

Comment: @greysnow Did this answer your question? If so, please feel free to mark this answer as "accepted".